# Regex not working to test Mobile Number

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a regex that tests for mobile nos (10 digit, starting digit can be 7,8 or 9)

I worked out this   ->   /^(7|8|9)[\d]{9,9}$/

My code is

```
function testPhone()
    {
       var pattern = /^(7|8|9)[\d]{9,9}$/;
        var phoneNo = document.getElementById('phoneNo');

            if (!pattern.test(phoneNo))
            {
                alert("It is not valid mobile number!");
            }

    }



 <input type="text" name="phoneNo"  maxlength="10"  size="10"  >
 <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="testPhone()">
```

Somehow it always displays the alert message.
I also tested my regex here (http://www.regextester.com/) . It works here.
Please help.

Comment: Try logging the `phoneNo`, and you'll see what is wrong with your code (if not, tell us what was logged). Also, your regex is overcomplicated.

Answer (score 4):

It's

```
var phoneNo = document.getElementById('phoneNo').value;
```

Note the `.value`.

Oh, and your input doesn't have an `id`.

Answer (score 3):

you forgot `.value`,

```
var phoneNo = document.getElementById('phoneNo').value;
```

try this pattern,

```
^[7-9](\d){9}$
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
var phoneNo = document.getElementById('phoneNo').value;
                                                   ^
```

and regex should be

```
/^(7|8|9)\d{9}$/
```

no need of  `{9,9}` and `[\d]`

Comment: I tried that but now it doesnt display Alert even for the wrong ones.

Comment: @user905911 this is the right regex...i guess you had missed `/yourRegex/`..check out the edited regex